# Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting : Exception type: CloudException, Message: Metric category 'AllMetrics' is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I am getting below exception:

> Exception type: CloudException, Message: Metric category 'AllMetrics'
>   is not supported.

Running Azure PowerShell command `Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting` for any **Storage Account**, same command works fine other resource type like **Key Vault**, **Service Bus**, **Load Balancers** etc.

**Azure PowerShell command:**

> Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $ResourceId -Enable $true
>   -RetentionInDays 365 -RetentionEnabled $true

**Exception details:**

```
Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting : Exception type: CloudException, Message: Metric category 'AllMetrics' is not
supported., Code: BadRequest, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: Bad Request
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId '/subscriptions/c1ddf901-1db ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Diagnostics.SetAzureRmDiagnosticSettingCommand
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Also tried specifying parameter `-StorageAccountId $StorageAccountIdLogs` with different Storage Account resource ID, still getting same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Metric category 'AllMetrics' is not supported.

According to the error message, **AllMetrics** is not supported to **Azure Storage Account**.

To enable metrics of **Storage Account**, you could use [`Set-AzureStorageServiceMetricsProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageservicemetricsproperty?view=azurermps-6.1.0).

You could refer to my sample command, it works fine on my side.

```
C:\PS>$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <StorageAccountName > -StorageAccountKey <StorageAccountKey >
C:\PS>Set-AzureStorageServiceMetricsProperty -ServiceType Blob -MetricsType Hour -MetricsLevel Service -Pass Thru -RetentionDays 10 -Version 1.0 -Context $Context
```

[image]
For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enabling-storage-metrics-and-viewing-metrics-data#how-to-enable-storage-metrics-using-powershell).

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, even after running Set-AzureStorageServiceMetricsProperty command, I am still getting same 'AllMetrics' is not supported exception running Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting, next to that

Comment: I am talking about `Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting` command, not `Set-AzureStorageServiceMetricsPropert`

Comment: @rajeshmag I think `Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting` not support the storage account , Storage Metrics is enabled by default when you create a new storage account, Storage metrics is available for the Blob, Queue, Table, and File services.

Comment: Thanks @Joy, Azure resource-level diagnostic logs is not supported for Storage Account yet. Article for available list of [supported services, schemas and categories for Azure Diagnostic Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-diagnostic-logs-schema)